# Django how to copy subset of object values to a new object?

Tags: python, django

I need to create a new Django DB object by inheriting some values from an existing objects.

If I just wanted to create a new copy of an objects I would simply do this:

```
objB =OBJ.objects.get(pk=objA_id)
objB.pk = None
objB.save()
```

But I want only copy certain values from the object. So I would do something like this and simply override the old values I don't want:

```
objB =OBJ.objects.get(pk=objA_id)
objB.pk = None
objB.key1 = value1
objB.key2 = value2
objB.key3 = None
objB.save()
```

My question is if there is a better or “pythonic” way to do that?

Comment: There's nothing inherently ugly with what you're doing, but it's hard to tell you if there's a more elegant approach without more context.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what exactly it is you're trying to achieve. Maybe, clarify what exactly it is you're attempting to implement.

One thing I WILL say though, is you absolutely do **NOT** want to write code that nullifies your PK or ID without providing a replacement or alternate primary key for it to be referenced with in the database. An object without an ID simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Nulling the PK on the object doesn't actually make the PK null in the database. Indeed that could never work. What it does is make it so that when the object is eventually saved Django will assign it a new PK. OP is basically using this as a trick to create a new object without having to create it from scratch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).